# Can't connect Node.js to remote database MariaDB

Tags: node.js, mariadb

I try to connect to my MariaDB database using Node.js based on [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/getting-started-with-the-nodejs-connector/) tutorial:

```
    const mariadb = require('mariadb');
const pool = mariadb.createPool({
     host: 'myhost.com',
     user:'root', 
     password: 'password',
     database: 'db_p',
     connectionLimit: 2
});

async function asyncFunction() {
  let conn;
  try {
    console.log('establishing connection')
    conn = await pool.getConnection();
    console.log('established')
    const rows = await conn.query("SHOW TABLES");
    console.log(rows);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
      throw err;
  } finally {
      if (conn) return conn.end();
  }
}
```

but all I get is this error:

```
establishing connection
{ Error: retrieve connection from pool timeout
    at Object.module.exports.createError (/Users/jan/Developer/microservice/node_modules/mariadb/lib/misc/errors.js:55:10)
    at rejectTimeout (/Users/jan/Developer/microservice/node_modules/mariadb/lib/pool.js:267:16)
    at Timeout.rejectAndResetTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/Users/jan/Developer/microservice/node_modules/mariadb/lib/pool.js:287:5)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:486:15)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
  fatal: false,
  errno: 45028,
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  code: 'ER_GET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT' }
(node:76515) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: retrieve connection from pool timeout
    at Object.module.exports.createError (/Users/jan/Developer/microservice/node_modules/mariadb/lib/misc/errors.js:55:10)
    at rejectTimeout (/Users/jan/Developer/microservice/node_modules/mariadb/lib/pool.js:267:16)
    at Timeout.rejectAndResetTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/Users/jan/Developer/microservice/node_modules/mariadb/lib/pool.js:287:5)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:486:15)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
(node:76515) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This errororiginated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or byrejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:76515) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I programmed in JS for last two years, but I'm new to Node.js and I thought it should work out of the box. Anyone?

Comment: So the connection to the database timed out. Can you access the database through other means (like a command line client) from the machine that is also running your Node code?

Comment: Not really. I have access to phpMyAdmin and the reason I use Node is because our developer is gone and I need to create microservice that connects to database so we're not left in the dark. PHP code points `localhost` so I found hostname in phpMyAdmin but still the same error

Comment: I tried using `mysql` package and I got `Error: ER_HOST_NOT_PRIVILEGED: Host 'my ip here' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Comment: That's another problem, but one that is possibly easier to solve (grant permission to the client's IP-address).

Comment: Ok, problem solved - I granted permission to my ip. Of course it's just for now, but at least I can work now :) Thanks for help!

Comment: @jeand'arme - Yes, that's the likely answer.  Self-Answer this Question, then Accept your Answer.  (Let's get this Question Closed without deleting it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that in phpMyAdmin I didn't added my home ip address so I can connect. For those who are just starting with it - you can create multiple users with the same name and password so you can actually have access from multiple IP's (like `localhost`, `::1` or `127.0.0.1` which is quite the same, but still required just for sure).

I have added additional user with same credentials pointing to my IP and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

For others with the same error message, particularly if the connection works the first few times but not after that, the error can happen if you don't end the connection with conn.end. Not OPs problem, but perhaps others.

Comment: Cheers! I was using `conn.release()` when I was using `pool.connect()` (which is intended for `pool.getConnection()`). Using `conn.end()` solved my problem.

Comment: @pxljoy your comment solved the issue, thx

Comment: @pxljoy your comment solved the issue, thx

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was solved by adding `port: 3307` as another `pool` creation parameter.

[Port 3306 seems to be default](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/mariadb/get-started/understand-default-config-mariadb/) but some servers seem to prefer 3307.