# nodejs not able to connect to maria db. Able to connect through command line

Tags: node.js, mariadb

I am getting the following error when connecting to db

```
node_server_1   | Error connecting to database: (conn=-1, no: 45028, SQLState: HY000) retrieve connection from pool timeout after 10002ms
node_server_1   |     (pool connections: active=0 idle=0 limit=10)
node_server_1   | SqlError: (conn=-1, no: 45028, SQLState: HY000) retrieve connection from pool timeout after 10002ms
node_server_1   |     (pool connections: active=0 idle=0 limit=10)
node_server_1   |     at Object.module.exports.createError (/home/simha/app/node_modules/mariadb/lib/misc/errors.js:57:10)
node_server_1   |     at Pool._requestTimeoutHandler (/home/simha/app/node_modules/mariadb/lib/pool.js:344:26)
node_server_1   |     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
node_server_1   |     at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
node_server_1   |   text: 'retrieve connection from pool timeout after 10002ms\n' +
node_server_1   |     '    (pool connections: active=0 idle=0 limit=10)',
node_server_1   |   sql: null,
node_server_1   |   fatal: false,
node_server_1   |   errno: 45028,
node_server_1   |   sqlState: 'HY000',
node_server_1   |   code: 'ER_GET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
node_server_1   | }
```

and this is my code

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import mariadb from "mariadb";

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  dotenv.config();
}

console.log(process.env.DB_HOST)
console.log(process.env.DB_USER)
console.log(process.env.DB_PASSWORD)
console.log(process.env.DB_NAME)

const pool = mariadb.createPool({
  hostname: 'mariadb',
  user: 'simha',
  password: 'krishna',
  database: 'blogs'
});




try {
  console.log(process.env.DB_HOST,process.env.DB_USER,process.env.DB_PASSWORD,process.env.DB_NAME)
  const conn = await pool.getConnection();
  console.log("Connected to database.");
  conn.release();
} catch (err) {
  console.error("Error connecting to database:", err.message);
  console.log(err)
  await pool.end();
  process.exit(1);
}

export default pool;
```

I am able to connect to the database using command line

```
mariadb --host mariadb -P 3306 --user simha –pkrishna
```

not able to understand whats the issue

Comment: I'm also facing this issue. I can connect to the same database from SQL Developer IDE, so I doubt it's a network or firewall issue.  @paulsm4's answer below did not help.  I'm using Node version 20.10.0, and mariadb module version 3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be a "network connectivity" issue.

Q: Is your node app running on the same host - with the same IP - as the host where you verified the command line?

FOR EXAMPLE:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/53418273/421195
>
> The problem was that in phpMyAdmin I didn't added my home ip address
> so I can connect. For those who are just starting with it - you can
> create multiple users with the same name and password so you can
> actually have access from multiple IP's (like localhost, ::1 or
> 127.0.0.1 which is quite the same, but still required just for sure).
>
> I have added additional user with same credentials pointing to my IP
> and it solved the problem.

ANOTHER POSSIBILITY:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/68406734/421195
>
> For others with the same error message, particularly if the connection
> works the first few times but not after that, the error can happen if
> you don't end the connection with conn.end. Not OPs problem, but
> perhaps others.

FINALLY: everything might actually be working correctly:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/52225583/421195
>
> Each connection in the pool will time out, because using release()
> does not close the connection but give it back to the pool.
>
> So your disconnects are pretty normal and you should handle the error
> appropriately.
>
> The connections are recreated automatically, see
> https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#poolcluster-options

This example might give you some helpful tips:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/59761773/421195
>
> **Retry to connect with setTimeout():**
>
> ```
> 'use strict';
>
> const dbpool = require('mysql').createPool({
>     connectionLimit: 10,
>     acquireTimeout: 30000,
>     waitForConnections: true,
>     database: 'mydatabase',
>     host: 'localhost',
>     multipleStatements: true,
>     password: 'mypassword',
>     user: 'root',
> });
>
> const sql = 'SELECT * FROM sometable;';
>
> const attemptConnection = () =>
>   dbpool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
>   if (err) {
>     console.log('error connecting. retrying in 1 sec');
>     setTimeout(attemptConnection, 1000);
>   } else {
>     connection.query(sql, (errQuery, results) => {
>       connection.release();
>       if (errQuery) {
>         console.log('Error querying database!');
>       } else {
>         console.log('Successfully queried database.');
>       }
>     });
>   }
> });
>
> attemptConnection();
> ```

Comment: i am able to access the server from command line

Comment: 1) I asked if you were absolutely 100% certain that the "successful" command line was using *THE SAME HOST ... AND THE SAME IP* as the "failed" connection.  2) Moreover, please look at the *OTHER* suggestions.  3) Please keep us posted what you find!

Comment: 1) Your example doesn't actually do any work: it just tries to grab a connection from the pool, and either releases it, or - on failure - calls. .end().  Q:  Is the problem intermittent, or does it *ALWAYS* timeout? 2) Your code connects to database "blob", but your command line uses the default database.  Q:  What happens if you try `mariadb --host mariadb -P 3306 --user simha –pkrishna blob`?  3) Is your NodeJS app co-located on the same host has your MySql DB? 4) You might want to add  .createPool(), options, like these: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59761773/421195